# Express Middlewares execute their arguments, while JavaScript functions doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to write an express middleware, I'm calling it **express-stack-player**.

What this middleware does is that it gives your middlewares access to the objects **(req, res, next)**, by getting the benefit of the [JavaScript scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) ex:

[image]

The following is a very simplified version of its code, which sums up its core job of it:

```js
const stackPlayer = (stacks) => (req, res, next) => {
  // @param stacks: function
  const stacksValue = stacks(req, res, next);
  for (middleware of stacksValue) {
    middleware(req, res, next);
  }
};
```

It used to work during my project which I'm working on until eventually, I discovered an unwanted behaviour by running the following test:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const setter = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("hello world");
  req.a = {};
  req.a.b = 1;
  next();
};
const readSomething = (something) => (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(something);
};

const stackPlayer = (stacks) => (req, res, next) => {
  // @param stacks: function
  const stacksValue = stacks(req, res, next);
  for (middleware of stacksValue) {
    middleware(req, res, next);
  }
};

app.get(
  "/",
  stackPlayer((req, res, next) => [setter, readSomething(req.a.b)])
);

console.clear();
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening on port 4000"));
```

When I run `npm start`, it prints the following in the terminal just normally:

[image]

But when I request `GET /`, the following error prints out:

[image]

I was testing this JavaScript code in the browser to see its behavior:

```js
const obj = {}

const setOnObj = () => {
  obj.a = {}, obj.a.b = 1
}

const readSomething = (arg) => {
  console.log(arg)
}

setOnObj()
readSomething(obj.a.b)
```

If you click on `Run code snippet`, the output will be `1`. So why does my **express-stack-player** package have a different behavior?

By the way, [the package is on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@samislam/switcher), and it can be downloaded by running

```js
npm i @samislam/switcher
```

In the past, I made a bigger package called switcher, but now I want to move the core logic of executing the middlewares into a separate package, and I'll call it **express-stack-player** *(if the name would be available by then)*.

Comment: `[setter, readSomething(req.a.b)]` and hence `req.a.b` is evaluated _before_ any of these two middleware functions is executed. At this point, `req.a = undefined`. Also, calling multiple middlewares in the way `stackPlayer` does it may not work, for example, if both middlewares call `next()`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, Thanks for your reply, about the second part of your comment, I know that, it's not a problem, this is just a demonistration sample, the `next` logic is already written in my code. And about the first part , it looks like yes, that's the whole problem, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem, it's really tricky

Comment: @Normal as mentioned earlier there's quite a bit about the code structure that could be optimised. But to solve your problem, you could define the readSomething function as so `const readSomething = (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.a.b); };` and also change the line of code where it's being called to `[setter, readSomething]`.

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo, that does not answer the question, readSomething isn't hard-coded to read something, it accepts an argument

Comment: Your `setter` middleware is responsible for adding the properties `a` and `b` to the request object which then calls next. The subsequent middleware will be returned from calling `readSomething`. But with the way your code is structured when you call `readSomething` the `setter` middleware hasn't even been called so `a` and `b` cannot exist on the req object so if you definitely need to invoke `readSomething(req.a.b)` then the `setter` middleware needs to be called first either `app.get("/", [setter, stackPlayer((req, res, next) => [readSomething(req.a.b)])]);` or using `app.use(setter)` first